# Adding Labels and images dynamically to a custom view in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a `custom view` that I made to capture user's signature on `Android`. The `view` is working fine and I am getting the results I want. Now I need to add watermarks (little texts on the four corners of the background of the signature box). I am doing this on Android and iOS, so what I did on iOS was to create `label`s, and using some configs I calculate the `frame (x,y,width,heigh)` at runtime and add them to the custom view. This works great on iOS (MonoTouch). Now I need to do the same thing on MonoForAndroid.

So far I have got this:

```
// my customView
public signatureView : View, ISignatureView
{
    // some irrelvant code here

    // then OnDraw (which is where I draw the signature line)   
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        DrawWaterMarks();
    }   

    private void DrawWaterMarks()
    {
        // First, I create a RelativeLayout and add it to my customView to hold the labels
        _relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.Context);
        var layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.MeasuredWidth, this.MeasuredHeight);
        _relativeLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParam;
        var viewGroup = (ViewGroup)this.RootView;
        viewGroup.AddView(_relativeLayout);

        // I then create the labels
        ILabel label = new Label(Context);
        label.Layout(watermark.x, watermark.y, 0,0);
        EnsureAddingWatermarkControl(label);

    }

    private void EnsureAddingWatermarkControl(View view)
    {
        if (_relativeLayout != null && view != null)
        {
            _relativeLayout.RemoveView(view);
            _relativeLayout.AddView(view, view.MeasuredWidth, view.MeasuredHeight);
            this.Invalidate();
        }           
    }

}
```

Now the code above all works fine and there is no exception or error, but I cannot see any of my labels.

I am assuming it is the RelativeLayout and the setting of the dimensions and the way I am doing it, but cannot work out where the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing a reference of my `RelativeLayout` that holds the `SignatureView` and using that to hold the newly (dynamically) created labels (`TextView`) and watermarks. This worked great. Before every `relativeLayout.Add(view)`, I do `relativeLayout.Remove(view)` to ensure that I do not `add` the same `view` twice to the layout (which could throw an `exception`). I will write a blog post about this sometime soon and will update my answer here to include that

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may be, it displays the relative layout added already in `onDraw`. So add your relative layout in `rootview` either after or inside this method

```
EnsureAddingWatermarkControl(View view)
```

You gave the comment below in your code.

> // First, I create a RelativeLayout and add it to my customView to
>   hold the labels

First you should add your `label`s to your relative layout and then you should add your relative layout to your `customView`(as mentioned in the code snippet given by you)

so your code should be like

```
private void DrawWaterMarks()
{
        ILabel label = new Label(Context);
        label.Layout(watermark.x, watermark.y, 0,0);
        EnsureAddingWatermarkControl(label);

}
private void EnsureAddingWatermarkControl(View view)
{
        if (view != null)
        {
           _relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.Context);
        var layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.MeasuredWidth, this.MeasuredHeight);
        _relativeLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParam;
                    _relativeLayout.AddView(view, view.MeasuredWidth, view.MeasuredHeight);

        var viewGroup = (ViewGroup)this.RootView;
        viewGroup.AddView(_relativeLayout);


            this.Invalidate();
        }           
}
```

Comment: do I need to add it again? I thought I need to add it once.. I will give this a try

Comment: Ur changed relative layout is not reflected bcoz, your rootview dont know its modified.

Comment: var viewGroup = (ViewGroup)this.RootView;
Can you explain why you are using this above line?

Comment: Edited my answer. Give it a try once

Comment: In the link you followed they are using fragments. So their view can be casted into ViewGroup, bcoz the view they are going to inflate will be a layout. Here you are using a view. not a layout.

Comment: Thanks Priya, I did like you said and tried your solution, but that did not change anything. The views (labels) are added to the RelativeLayout and the relative layout is added to the RootView, but nothing is showing up. any idea?